# Installing modules on Active Perl 5.6 on Windows

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I am using ActivePerl 5.6.1 Build 635 (let's assume that I absolutely have to work with this version and cannot update to a newer one) on a Windows XP machine. The ppm version with this version of Perl is 2.2.0 and is not the same as the ppm for later versions (as mentioned [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=A%20guide%20to%20installing%20modules%20for%20Win32) ). I am trying to accomplish a simple task : INSTALLING THE PERL MODULE "RPC::XML". Here is a list of things I have done :

1 : Tried installing using CPAN (one of many links as to how to do this is [here](http://perl.about.com/od/packagesmodules/qt/perlcpan.htm)) but the make commands won't run on my command line as I do not have nmake installed.

2 : Tried using [ppm](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=A%20guide%20to%20installing%20modules%20for%20Win32). However I get the following error despite using a direct internet connection.

```
**PPM> search "RPC::XML"
Error connecting to 'http://ppm.ActiveState.com/cgibin/PPM/ppmserver.pl?urn:/PPMServer'.**
```

Also I have read that some perl modules for versions 5.8 and above are not even compatible with version 5.6. The activeperl website doesn't even have a version for download for verison 5.6 (as can be seen [here](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/RPC-XML/)).

So my problem is simple. 
All I want to do is install a perl module (RPC::XML say) on 5.6.1 using 2.2.0. Also let me know why ppm seems to be unable to connect when I am using a simple direct internet connection.

I am about 2 days old to perl. Ignore any noob statements I might have written, and correct me.

Comment: [That link](http://ppm.ActiveState.com/cgibin/PPM/ppmserver.pl?urn:/PPMServer) does indeed appear not to exist. That might be related to the fact that Perl 5.6.1 was released more than 12 years ago. Is there a reason you can't install `nmake`?

Comment: "let's assume that I absolutely have to work with this version and cannot update to a newer one" - well that's rarely true. But if you're going to insist on using a version of Perl that is 12 years old, then you're going to have to accept that some of the infrastructure may have bitrot.

Answer (score 2):

The nice folks at ActiveState give free access to their PPM repositories for folks using their 2 latest releases of perl.  Access to their legacy repositories is available for a price.

As such your choices seem to be:

- install nmake & use cpan (may also require a c compiler for some modules)
- install a relatively modern copy of perl (i.e. free support)
- shell out cash for an 'enterprise' subscription of ActivePerl and get your stuff via ppm. (Of course even the Activestate folks my not choose to support any software versions that old.)
- do without any of the above, manually parse the make file & type in the commands yourself.